# Soft Keyboard covers TextInput on the SlidingUpPanel flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textinput

This is the [package](https://github.com/akshathjain/sliding_up_panel) am using , when I use a TextInput within the `panelBuilder`  it has both the ListView and the InputTextField, however when I start typing the Soft keyboard covers the InputText field.

I also tried to add this line :

`resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` in the `Scaffold` plus this one in the Manfiest file

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` .

But no luck.

Below are the screenshots :

[image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7r8F.png)

[[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8qrv.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the contents of your `panelBuilder` result in a `Scaffold` and don't change `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`.  By default the resize is `true` which will move the content up to avoid being hidden by keyboard when it appears.  A `false` setting prevents the resize from happening.

The below example is from the [slide_up_panel package example](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel/example), with the `panelBuilder` argument result wrapped in a `Scaffold`.  (I'm not suggesting you wrap `_panel` like I've done below, it's just easier to show the example working this way.  Likely better to use Scaffold within the `_panel` function itself.)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    _panelHeightOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .80;

    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[

          SlidingUpPanel(
            maxHeight: _panelHeightOpen,
            minHeight: _panelHeightClosed,
            parallaxEnabled: true,
            parallaxOffset: .5,
            body: _body(),
            // WRAP panel contents in Scaffold
            panelBuilder: (sc) => Scaffold(body: _panel(sc)),
            // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0), topRight: Radius.circular(18.0)),
            onPanelSlide: (double pos) => setState((){
              _fabHeight = pos * (_panelHeightOpen - _panelHeightClosed) + _initFabHeight;
            }),
          ),
```

To test yourself add a TextFormField to the bottom of the `Widget _panel(ScrollController sc)` method (around line 242)

```
            SizedBox(height: 24,),
            // ↓ Added for testing
            TextFormField(
              initialValue: 'type here',
              onSaved: (txt) => null,
            )
```

Then run the example, scroll the panel upwards and tap the TextField to have the keyboard slide up.

[image: panel pushed up by keyboard]

Comment: Thanks a bunch  @Baker, you saved my life

Comment: I have a similar problem with this but in the *body* of the sliding_up_panel, no matter that you wrapped your underneath widget with a Scaffold it still does not work and the keyboard hides the content, any idea?